# Cannot return schema tables including pks and fk

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Need to populate a dataset with all the tables in the database and each datatable must have the following column

- TableName
- ColumnName
- IsNullable,
- DataType
- MaxLength
- IsprimaryKey
- IsForeignKey

I have done the following but this done not give me the primarykeys and foreignkeys

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C      
WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' 
ORDER BY C.TABLE_NAME
```

Tried to add a joint but I get wrong result

```
SELECT C.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    C.TABLE_NAME,
    C.COLUMN_NAME,
    C.IS_NULLABLE,
    C.DATA_TYPE,
    C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
    TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    INNER JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC 
        ON c.TABLE_NAME=TC.TABLE_NAME
WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' 
ORDER BY C.TABLE_NAME
```

How do I return all the info above about a table including if's a primary of foreignkey?

Thanks alot

Comment: I ran the same **`Query`**, I didn't find **`Error`**. What exactly are you not getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correct then :

1.You need do `LEFT join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`

2.Put the `case`

Try the below Query and let me know if i am correct?

```
SELECT 
Distinct
C.TABLE_SCHEMA,
C.TABLE_NAME,
C.COLUMN_NAME,
C.IS_NULLABLE,
C.DATA_TYPE,
C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
CASE WHEN TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY' THEN 'Yes' Else 'No' end as ISprimaryKey,
CASE WHEN TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY' THEN 'Yes' Else 'No' end as IsForeignKey
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C with(nolock)
LEFT join  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC with(nolock) on c.TABLE_NAME=TC.TABLE_NAME
WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' 
ORDER BY C.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: hi,thanks for your reply however I get more than double the rows though ,any ideas

Comment: Hi thanks for your time still getting double columns ,this seems to be caused by "the case when" tried to group by but cannot seem to group by the case when.thanks again

Comment: Also noticed that it adds twice the same column once with primary key and then with foreign key.

Comment: Distinct's not enough, you'll need to aggregate this (GROUP BY) taking the MAX from the two CASE columns.

Comment: @RBarryYoung hi could you provide an example on how you would do it thanks a lot for your time